# Can not find by xpath until inspect the element

Tags: selenium, xpath, iframe, queryselector

I was using Selenium *find_element_by_xpath* to click the cookie popup "Accept" button. But it was failing to find the button. So, I tried to locate the button using *querySelector* in the dev console. Also, the *querySelector* failed to find the button but after clicking inspect on the button the *querySelector* able to find the button.

Also, searching the xpath in dev elements just showing 1 of 1.

Why this is happening ? How do I click the "Accept" button using selenium ?

Website link: https://www.transfermarkt.com/

The xpath: `//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/div[2]/button`

[image: can not locate the button]

After inspect on the button.

[image: can locate the button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That element is inside an iframe, so to access it you will first have to switch to that iframe.
You didn't mention what language are you using so I will give my solution in Python. This can be done with other languages as well with some little syntax changes.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'iframe[title="SP Consent Message"]')))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@title="ACCEPT ALL"]'))).click()
```

When finished working inside this iframe you will have to switch back to the default content with

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```